# Bootstrap 3 Carousel with thumbnails (image and text)

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem. How can I center the image and the text in the thumbnail ?
And how can I change it that the text dynamically change the font size and don't write over the thumbnail.

Here is my Code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
    <a id="tileF" href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item">
          <img src="HERE IS MY IMAGE" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <p>
            <h4>HERE IS MY TEXT.</h4>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 0):

setting `text-align: center;` to the parent element will center a child text element or img element to the middle of it.

e.g.

```
<p style="text-align:center;"><img><h3>Heading Text</h3></p>
```

In terms of Changing the font size this would require either a media query if it is related to the size of the screen, or if it was something conditional that has to be done in css I would suggest something like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) or [Less](http://lesscss.org/) which has functionality that will allow you to have conditional (although limited) css. I would suggest constructing your design in a way in which this wouldn't be necessary though as very rarely would you need to change the font size based on the current size of an element.

Comment: Bootstrap has a `text-center` class for that.